# Add input type file in html template using knockoutjs

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have created custom module in which I have created front-end template form using knockout js.

I want to add input-type `file` . I want to save file in `folder` and store it's name in `database` on form `submit` ,

please help me if anyone has did this ?